# How to display a <span> element in angular template on form validation?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, reactive

So I'm doing this angular reactive-form project and I have an interesting question. 
My task is to show errors in validation with a span beneath each form input that is invalid. Form input should be validated on outclicking from it and the form should be validated onSubmit. 
I need my span elements to be rendered on outclick but in the same time, same spans should be rendered should I have never entered anything in any input and submited the form. 
So, either I input something invalid and form tells me about it with a span or I click on Submit button and form shows spans of each invalid input. 
I would like all spans to be added programmaticly, but through the template should be fine too. 
My logic would be to save all the "errors" (basicly, the content of each span) to an array and to save all the statuses into an array and by looping and template-binding, show them.
I can't figure out neither the logic for my idea, nor a simpler solution. Help me please.

My template:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form__group form__group--name">
        <div class="form__control form__first-name">
            <input type="text" name="Fname" required formControlName="firstName" a-ngblur="onBlur(true)">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__last-name">
            <input type="text" name="Lname" required formControlName="lastName">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form__group--id">
        <div class="form__control form__email">
            <input type="text" name="email" required formControlName="email">
            <label>Email ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__ID">
            <input type="text" name="ID" required formControlName="id">
            <label>Your User ID</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form__group--location form-group">
        <div class="form__control form__country">
            <span>Country</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="country" formControlName="country" (change)="onChange()" (click)="onOpen('country')">
                <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose your country</option>
                <option  *ngFor="let country of countries"  [value]="country.value">{{ country.value }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__location">
            <div class="form__location--state" [ngSwitch]="this.signUpForm.get('country').value">
                <span>State</span>
                <select name="state" formControlName="state" *ngSwitchCase="'USA'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose state</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let state of statesUSA"  [value]="state.value">{{ state.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="state" formControlName="state" *ngSwitchCase="'India'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose state</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let state of statesIndia"  [value]="state.value">{{ state.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="state" formControlName="state" *ngSwitchCase="undefined">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose state</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form__location--city" [ngSwitch]="this.signUpForm.get('state').value">  
                <span>City</span>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city" *ngSwitchCase="'New York'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose city</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let city of citiesNY"  [value]="city.value">{{ city.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city" *ngSwitchCase="'California'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose city</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let city of citiesCali"  [value]="city.value">{{ city.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city" *ngSwitchCase="'Andhra Pradesh'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose city</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let city of citiesAndhra"  [value]="city.value">{{ city.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city" *ngSwitchCase="'Goa'">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose city</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let city of citiesGoa"  [value]="city.value">{{ city.value }}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city" *ngSwitchCase="undefined">
                    <option [value]="null" disabled>Choose city</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form__control--data">
        <div class="form__control form__phone">
            <input type="text" name="phone" required formControlName="phone" #phoneInput
            [imask]="{mask: '+{38}(000)000-00-00'}" [unmask]="true">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__code">
            <input type="text" name="code" class="ref-code" formControlName="code" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
            <label>Reference Code</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form__group--buttons">
        <a type="button" (click)="onReset()" class="form__group--buttons-reset">Reset All</a>
        <button type="submit" class="form__group--buttons-submit">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { storageService } from '../storage-service.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;
  countries = [
    new FormControl('USA'),
    new FormControl('India')
  ];

  statesUSA = [new FormControl('New York'), new FormControl('California')];
  statesIndia = [new FormControl('Andhra Pradesh'), new FormControl('Goa')]

  citiesNY = [new FormControl('Albany'), new FormControl('New York City')];
  citiesCali = [new FormControl('Sacramento'), new FormControl('Los Angeles'), new FormControl('San Francisco')];
  citiesAndhra = [new FormControl('Visakhapatnam'), new FormControl('Amaravati')];
  citiesGoa = [new FormControl('Panaji'), new FormControl('Vasco da Gama')];

  @ViewChild('phoneInput', {static: false}) phoneInput: ElementRef;
  public mask:any = {
    mask: '+{38}(0__)000-00-00',
    lazy: false
  }

  invalidMessages = ['This field is required and has to contain 2-32 cyrillic characters!', 
  'This field is required and has to be a valid email address!',
  'This is a required field!',
  'This is a required field! Please enter your telephone number, formated as "0__-___-__-__"',
  'This field is required and has to contain 2-32 cyrillic characters',
  'This is a required field! It has to contain from 5 to 30 latin characters and "_"',
  'This is a required field!',
  'This is a required field!',
  'This field has to contain from 1 to 10 latin characters or numbers.'];

  public statusArr : string[] = [];

  constructor(private storageService: storageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
      'firstName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^\S{2,255}@\S+\.\S+$/iu)]),
      'country': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'phone': new FormControl(null),
      'lastName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
      'id': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_]{5,30}\b/)]),
      'state': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'city': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'code': new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,10}\b/)])
    });

    if(this.storageService.savedForm) this.signUpForm.setValue(this.storageService.savedForm);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if(this.signUpForm.status === 'VALID') {
      this.storageService.savedForm = this.signUpForm.value;
      console.log(this.signUpForm);
    } else {
      let namesArr = Object.keys(this.signUpForm.controls);
      console.log(namesArr);
      for(let i = 0; i < namesArr.length; i++) {
        this.statusArr.push(this.signUpForm.controls[namesArr[i]].status);
      }
      console.log(this.statusArr);
    }
  }

  onReset() {

  }

  onChange() {
   (<FormGroup>this.signUpForm.get('state').value) = null;
   (<FormGroup>this.signUpForm.get('city').value) = null;
  }

  onOpen(controlName: string) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below approach, I have done for one form control alone, if it works add for all others too.
In HTML

```
<div class="form__control form__first-name">
    <input type="text" name="Fname" required formControlName="firstName" a-ngblur="onBlur(true)">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <span *ngIf="firstname.errors.required && firstname.touched">This field is required</span>
    <span *ngIf="firstname.errors.pattern && firstname.touched">Pattern not matching</span>
</div>
```

In component, add getters for all formcontrols.

```
get firstName(){
    this.signUpForm.get('firstName')
}
```

If you dont want to write getters, change it in the template like

```
<span *ngIf="signupForm.get('firstname').errors.required && signupForm.get('firstname').touched">This field is required</span>
```

replace touched with dirty for showing the errors only on clicking out(Blur from input).

As far as the submitting as concerned, dont allow the user to submit the form if the form is not valid(since angular runs all the validators after each value change), like disabling the button

```
<button [disabled]="signupForm.invalid">Submit form</button>
```